# Adding a HTML Page to a webservice developed using Apache CXF

Tags: web-services, cxf

I have created a Apache CXF Webservices .
It is working fine .
It was deployed successfuly  as a war file into Tomcat .

The Webservice is running fine

Means when i tried to access with

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringEx/HelloWorld?wsdl
```

it is fine

but when i tried to add a html page or a jsp page into its 
folder and tried to access

http://localhost:8080/SpringEx/Test.html

It gave me a error

No Service Found on to the browser

The Test.html is a simple page

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<FORM METHOD=POST >
What's your name? <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=username SIZE=20><BR>
What's your e-mail address? <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=email SIZE=20><BR>
What's your age? <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=age SIZE=4>
<P><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Do you have web.xml for this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your web service is running on Apache CXF servlet on context path: `SpringEx` which is defined in web application descriptor `web.xml`. Something like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SpringEx/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The reason you get this error is because `Apache CXF` servlet is mapped to only listen to that context: `SpringEx` and apply only to services defined in your `Spring` configuration (or not spring, depends on how you configuring your endpoint). It does not serve you any `HTML` or `JSP` pages.

This definitely not good idea to make a web service and then put some web front end in it. But anyway. If your `CXF` servlet is mapped as I showed you above you just simply put your `JSP` pages under `WEB-INF` folder and access them by do not defining `URL` pattern which applies only for web service.

Like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/Test.html
```

If your web services CXF servlet is mapped like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and the `SpringEx` is the name of the application, then you need to do something like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now your web service will be accessible through:

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringEx/services/HelloWorld?wsdl
```

And your `JSP` or `HTML` through:

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringEx/Test.html
```